# How to hash a string on windows/visual basic the same way as python's crypt.crypt()?

Tags: linux, windows, vb.net, hash, crypt

I have several (old) Linux systems that have users and passwords saved on a local database. The process is simple. Using python, you are asked to enter a password, the entered plain text passwords are processed using python's crypt module and the hashed password is then saved to the database.

For instance,

```
# Password.py   (not editable)
Debug = 1
import getpass
plain_pass = getpass.getpass()
# e.g. plain_pass="pass"
import crypt
crypt_pass = crypt.crypt( plain_pass, r'$1$xx')
# The salt r'$1$xx' can not be changed
if Debug:
    print (crypt_pass)   # Result:    $1$xx$Ik.nuioJufb1VPeTbLQ.y/
```

**(ignoring security issues for now)**
I want to provide a simple text file where username and hashed passwords are stored:

```
Sample Password.txt file
user1 $1$xx$Ik.nuioJufb1VPeTbLQ.y/
user2 $1$xx$x2gmo6Eob2udHl0tNU2Zw0          (password is 123)
```

A windows server will host the files for all the linux machines, it also provides a user interface where users can modify their passwords or new users can be created.

Using windows (VB or any other win application), **how to generate the same hashes** as with python's crypt.crypt()?

```
pass  --->  $1$xx$Ik.nuioJufb1VPeTbLQ.y/
123   --->  $1$xx$x2gmo6Eob2udHl0tNU2Zw0
hello --->  $1$xx$zrPVW4APkg66JghmAwqmA.
üfñ2  --->  $1$xx$CPthCTb1yiYoLfl3VmrJl/
```

Comment: According to the documentation, *the crypt(3) routine, which is a one-way hash function based upon a modified DES algorithm;*  Which gives you a starting point, but without knowing what is modified and how, you might not be able to match it.

Comment: It might be better/easier to have a small python scriptlet to perform the hash for you and call it from NET.  There are many many posts here on doing that

Comment: I read that crypt module can only run on unix.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19878202/2798727 Any ideas how to make it also run on windows?